# jQuery how to hide all the first level children div items in a div at one time?

Tags: jquery

I have a complex div part on my page which combined with divs as following:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">
    <div class="grandchild1" />
    <div class="grandchild2" />
  </div>
  <div class="child2">
    <div class="grandchild3"></div>
    <div class="grandchild4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I wonder how to hide div child1 and child2 at one time, I know $(' .parent div') will hide all the div inside of .parent div, I don't want to hide grandchildren level, because when I set child1 visible, the grandchild1 and grandchild2 are still invisible. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the direct descendent CSS selector:

```
$('.parent > div').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the child selector,

```
$('.parent > div').hide();
```

or get the children

```
$('.parent').children().hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [child](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) selector.

```
$('.parent > div').hide();
```